# how to write the curses window content to the file in python?

Tags: python-2.7, ncurses, curses, python-curses

I have created window in the curses and created my call flow (data). 
window = curses.newwin(2500, 2500, 0, 0)
How should i copy the window content(exact replica) to the file ?

Comment: @williamMcbrine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curses (the underlying library) has [`scr_dump`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/scr_dump.5.html#h2-PORTABILITY) for this purpose.  But the python binding lacks that feature.

In python, you'd have to make a function that used [`inch`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.inch) to retrieve characters from the screen and wrote them to a file.

The description of `inch` in the python reference makes it clear that it does not work for *wide* characters (e.g., UTF-8), but it's possible to do something...

Comment: Hi Thomas, 
Thanks 4 ur answer. I am getting below error, 
File "./my_box.py", line 194, in call
    output_file.write(inchar)
TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not int

191         for y in range(0,500):
192             for x in range(0,500):
193                 inchar = window.inch(y,x)
194                 output_file.write(inchar) 

Could you help me in resolve this ?

Comment: You need a sample program to discuss (and a new question).  But see the documentation: `inch` returns a number, not a character, while `write` expects a character.

Comment: Thanks. I ll add new question with the sample program.

Comment: I have added new question. Could you help me to solve that issue. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43583901/not-able-to-write-window-inchy-x-output-to-file-in-python

Answer (score 0):

`putwin()` and `getwin()` are the functions for saving and restoring an individual window, and they're available in Python.

Comment: I overlooked that, but suspect that OP will not be satisfied with any of the formats which I documented last week...