# Not able to write window.inch(y,x) output to file in python

Tags: python, curses

In the below program, after i created the window output. I want to redirect the output to the file. But i am not able to write the `window.inch(y,x)` output to the file.

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.6
import sys, getopt
import curses
from curses import wrapper

def call(stdscr):
        inputFile = ''
        try:
            opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],"hi:o:",["ifile=","ofile="])
        except getopt.GetoptError:
            print 'my_box.py -i <inputFile_With_Path>'
            sys.exit(2)
        for opt, arg in opts:
            if opt == '-h':
                print 'my_box.py -i <inputFile_With_Path>'
                sys.exit()
            elif opt == '-i':
                inputFile = arg

        output_file = open("/home/vparamasivam/Training/Python/output.txt", "w+")
        my_Dict = { }
        cur_y = 3
        cur_sbc = 30
        cur_EP1 = 10
        cur_uas = 50
        cur_UAC = 10
        sbc_cur = 24
        cur_poi = 2
        RED_TEXT = 1
        endPointCount = 0
        callCount = 0
        count = 0
        if not curses.has_colors():
            curses.endwin()
            print "no colors"
            sys.exit()
        else:
            curses.start_color()

        curses.init_pair(RED_TEXT, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_BLACK)

        window = curses.newwin(500, 500, 0, 0)
        window.box()

        fo = open(inputFile, "r");

        print "Name of the file :", fo.name
        print "File closed or not :", fo.closed


        window.addstr(1, 29, "SBC", curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
        window.vline(cur_y, cur_sbc, '|', 500)
        for line in fo:
            if (line.find("Receive Msg From:") != -1) :
                ip, l, p, s, msg = line.split(',')
                ipc, ip = ip.rsplit(' ',1)
                ip, port = ip.split('/')
                ipPort = ip + ':' + port
                s, msg, req_uri = msg.split(' ', 2)
                print "\n SIP message : ", msg, ' '
                print "Received from IP : ", ipPort, ' '
                callCount += 1
                if not my_Dict.has_key(ipPort):
                    endPointCount +=1
                    if endPointCount == 1:
                        window.addstr(1, 4, ipPort, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        window.vline(cur_y, cur_EP1, '|', 500)
                        new = {ipPort:cur_EP1}
                        my_Dict.update(new)
                        cur_EP1 += 7
                        cur_poi += 1
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, cur_EP1, msg, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        cur_poi += 1
                        cur_EP1 -= 6
                        window.hline(cur_poi, cur_EP1, '-', 18)
                        cur_EP1 += 18
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, cur_EP1, '>')
                    else :
                        sbc_cur +=20
                        if endPointCount != 2:
                            cur_uas +=20
                        window.addstr(1, sbc_cur, ipPort, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        window.vline(cur_y, cur_uas, '|', 500)
                        new = {ipPort:cur_uas}
                        my_Dict.update(new)
                        cur_poi +=2
                        cur_uas -=13
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, cur_uas, msg, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        cur_uas +=13
                        cur_poi +=1
                        cur_sbc +=1
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, cur_sbc, '<')
                        count = cur_uas - cur_sbc - 1
                        cur_sbc +=1
                        window.hline(cur_poi, cur_sbc, '-', count)
                        cur_sbc -=2
                else :
                    ep = my_Dict[ipPort]
                    if ep == cur_UAC :
                        ep += 7
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, ep, msg, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        cur_poi += 1
                        ep -= 6
                        window.hline(cur_poi, ep, '-', 18)
                        ep += 18
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, ep, '>')
                        cur_poi += 1
                    else :
                        cur_poi +=1
                        ep -=13
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, ep, msg, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        ep +=13
                        cur_poi +=1
                        cur_sbc +=1
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, cur_sbc, '<')
                        count = ep - cur_sbc - 1
                        cur_sbc +=1
                        window.hline(cur_poi, cur_sbc, '-', count)
                        cur_sbc -=2

            elif (line.find("Send Msg to:") != -1) :
                ip, l, p, s, msg = line.split(',')
                s, msg, status = msg.split(' ', 2)
                ipc, ip = ip.rsplit(' ',1)
                ip, port = ip.split('/')
                ipPort = ip + ':' + port
                print "\n SIP message : ", msg, ' '
                print "Sent to IP : ", ipPort, ' '
                callCount += 1
                if not my_Dict.has_key(ipPort):
                    endPointCount +=1
                    if endPointCount == 1:
                        window.addstr(1, 9, ipPort, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        window.vline(cur_y, cur_EP1, '|', 500)
                        new = {ipPort:cur_EP1}
                        my_Dict.update(new)
                        cur_poi +=1
                        cur_EP1 +=7
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, cur_EP1, msg, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        cur_poi +=1
                        cur_EP1 -=6
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, cur_EP1, '<')
                        cur_EP1 +=1
                        window.hline(cur_poi, cur_EP1, '-', 18)
                    else :
                        sbc_cur +=20
                        if endPointCount != 2:
                            cur_uas +=20
                        window.addstr(1, sbc_cur, ipPort, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        window.vline(cur_y, cur_uas, '|', 500)
                        new = {ipPort:cur_uas}
                        my_Dict.update(new)
                        cur_poi +=1
                        cur_uas -=13
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, cur_uas, msg, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        cur_uas +=13
                        cur_poi +=1
                        cur_sbc +=1
                        count = cur_uas - cur_sbc - 1
                        window.hline(cur_poi, cur_sbc, '-', count)
                        cur_uas -=1
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, cur_uas, '>')
                        cur_uas +=1
                        cur_sbc -=1
                else :
                    ep = my_Dict[ipPort]
                    if ep == cur_UAC :
                        cur_poi +=1
                        ep +=7
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, ep, msg, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        cur_poi += 1
                        ep -= 6
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, ep, '<')
                        ep +=1
                        window.hline(cur_poi, ep, '-', 18)
                        cur_poi += 1
                    else :
                        cur_poi +=1
                        ep -=13
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, ep, msg, curses.color_pair(RED_TEXT))
                        ep +=13
                        cur_poi +=1
                        cur_sbc +=1
                        count = ep - cur_sbc - 1
                        window.hline(cur_poi, cur_sbc, '-', count)
                        ep -=1
                        window.addstr(cur_poi, ep, '>')
                        cur_sbc -=1

        print ""
        for y in range(0,500):
            for x in range(0,500):
                inchar = window.inch(y,x)
                output_file.write(inchar)
        #curses.scr_dump(output_file)
        inchar = window.getch()
        output_file.close()
        fo.close()

def main(stdscr):

    call(stdscr)

wrapper(main)
```

Getting below error ,

> TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer,
>   not int
>
> @ inchar = window.getch()

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: @ThomasDickey    Please have a look

Comment: Error @ output_file.write(inchar) not in  inchar = window.getch()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
            output_file.write(inchar)
```

because `inchar` is a number, containing an 8-bit character and some video attributes.  You could convert that to a string using something like

```
            output_file.write(str(inchar))
```

but that introduces another problem: determining in your output file where the video attributes start (and end) and where your character actually is.

Comment: output_file.write(str(inchar)) --> It didn't work. It just prints the number returned by window.inch(y,x). I want the exact window replica into the file. 

Eg. if my window has "  A h     &" , Then file should have " A h     &"

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try the *window.getkey()* method rather than *[window.getch()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html?highlight=getch#curses.window.getch)*.

As noted in the documentation the *getch()* function can return a value outside the range of ASCII characters for various function, cursor and other keys.  *getkey()* will return a multi-character string identifying those characters which aren't simple ASCII. This is explained a bit here: [Curses Programming with Python](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html).  As noted the names of the non-ASCII keys are defined as top level symbols (constants) in the *curses* module all following the naming pattern **KEY_xxx**.

Try that.

As for your loop around *[window.inch()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html?highlight=window.inch#curses.window.inch)* ... you need to mask off the lower 8 bits of the return value from each call to that (*this_ascii_char = ret & 0xFF*, where *ret* was the integer returned by *window.inch()*).

The remaining bits are the curses attributes of the character at that location.  (It's not clear what you want to do with those.  If you want to store the attributes as well as the ASCII character than it looks like you'd need to write 16-bits of attributes for every ASCII character.  It might make sense to write all the ASCII from your X*Y raster of the screen, following by the packed binary of all the corresponding attributes.  Then when you read and processes the data you can *zip()* these two sections of the file together and feed them to your curses screen display loop.  But I'm just speculating.

The real lesson here is read those docs.  The links I've provided tell you what these functions are returning.

Comment: Error @ output_file.write(inchar) not in  inchar = window.getch()

Comment: I've added details about window.inch() vs. window.getch().  The overall issue is the same.  These functions are returning integer values which extend beyond the ASCII range.

Comment: Hi Jim,
I just wanted to print all the output data present in the window. 
Your answer "this_ascii_char = ret & 0xFF" solves that purpose. But it is not formatted one. It prints everything in single line. I want to write the window content to file exactly the way it is displaying in window.

I tried to write 16bits by this_ascii_char = ret & 0xFFFF . But it gives below error in the following code

ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)

val = (ret & 0xFFFF)
output_file.write(chr(val))

Comment: Your curses library/configuration is probably using escape sequences to position the cursor at the beginning of each line.  I would suggest adding your own newline (\n) characters after every X characters for a display of X by Y).  You should be able to get those using the curses stdscr.getmaxyx() method.

Comment: Hi Jim, 
Thank you so much for your reply. I got the logic. But i couldn't the get usage of stdscr.getmaxyx() method. Could you please briefly explain with some example how to add the /n character end of each line window ?

Comment: Did you account for the fact that the dimensions are returned as a tuple of **lines** (vertical first) by **columns** (horizontal)?  (This is a common source of confusion when working in curses because most of us think in term of x by y ... conventional cartesian co-ordinates ... and most graphics APIs express co-ordinates as vertical, then horizontal. Curses is the outlier in this regard.
Double check that first; then perhaps post a snippet of code where you try to perform a "raster scan" of the curses screen (nested for loops over x and y, reversing the numbers returned by **getmaxyx()**).

Comment: Hi Jim, 
Please find the snippet of code in the below question ,

http://stackoverflow.com/q/43781725/4956090

Comment: Hi Jim, Could you please help me in this regards.

Comment: Hi Jim, Please find the snippet of code in the below question , 
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16092658
Could you please help in this regards.